Handling pipe errors using the Async iterator API of csv-parse
How do I properly handle errors thrown by Parse() on a pipe? I need to catch and bubble up errors thrown by validateHeaders().
Header validator:
  validateHeader(headers: string[], expectedHeaders: string[]): string[] {
    const missingHeaders = expectedHeaders.filter(
      (expectedHeader) => !headers.includes(expectedHeader),
    );
    if (missingHeaders.length > 0) {
      throw new BadRequestException(
        `Missing header elements: "${missingHeaders.join(', ')}"`,
      );
    }
    return headers;
  }

CSV Parser:
async processCsv(filePath: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const csvParse = createReadStream(filePath)
        .pipe(
          parse({
            columns: (header) => {
              return this.validateHeader(
                header,
                UNIDADE_CSV_HEADERS,
              );
            },
            trim: true,
          }),
        )
        .on('error', (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });

      try {
        for await (const record of csvParse as AsyncIterable<CsvRowInterface>) {
          // Async code working with my CSV
        }
      } catch(error) {
        throw error
      }
    });
  }

Method caller:
  @Process()
  async parseCsv(job: Job<csvJobDto>): Promise<void> {
    const { filePath} = job.data;
    await this.processCsv(filePath);
  }

  ...

  @OnQueueFailed()
    onFailed(job: Job<csvJobDto>, err: any): void {
      this.logger.error(err);
    }
}

I'm currently using 'on' to handle the error but I don't know if this is the correct approach with Async Iterators, I couldn't find anything about it on the documentation.
